# Образ виндовс windows через acronis и на ПК всех дисков образ будет занимать столько же, сколько они и сейчас занимает?

Tags: windows, образ, раздел

Образ виндовс windows через acronis и на ПК всех дисков образ будет занимать столько же, сколько они и сейчас заним.?
Женя Женя Ученик (34), Вопрос открыт 1 минуту назад
Образ виндовс windows через acronis и на ПК всех дисков образ будет занимать столько же, сколько они и сейчас занимают ?

Вот например:
Диск C занято 109 гигабайт
Диск F занято 124 гигабайт
Диск G занято 61 гигабайт

Всего - 294 гигибайт

Я хочу сделать образ Windows и разделов дисков, которые на компьютере. У меня сейчас стоит SSD и Винчестер №1. Я правильно понимаю, что образ Windows и разделов дисков через acronis будет весить 294 гигибайт, который нужно будет сохранить на винчестер №2, которого еще нет, и я планирую купить под это дело ?. И если вынуть SSD и Винчестер №1, то я смогу на компьютере развернуть систему со всеми дисками на винчестер №2, и все настройки виндовс, сети, драйвер, настройки программ сохранятся со всеми настройками ?
Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понял ?

P.S. железо будет то же , где и стоял виндовс

Comment: Напишите, что вы конкретно хотите сделать? Винчестеры поменять? И напишите какой локальный диск на каком винчестере находится

Comment: Если вы меняете винчестер на другой винчестер, зачем тогда хотите SSD высунуть?

Comment: я хочу сохранить бэкап всего виндовса и всех разделов , чтобы можно было этот бекап опять развернуть , если слетит виндовс

Comment: *Я правильно понимаю, что образ Windows и разделов дисков через acronis будет весить 294 гигибайт* Не факт. 1) Акронис умеет архивировать создаваемый образ. 2) Файл размером в 1 байт может занимать и несколько Мб на диске. 3) В зависимости от типа архива хардлинки в образе могут сохраняться и как линки, и как два отдельных файла.